# Cross-Browser Extension using Crossrider

Tags: cross-browser, crossrider

I am trying to create a Cross-Browser Extension using Crossrider that will be able to manage browser bookmarks, monitor opened browser tabs/windows and save them to a remote server at user's request [when user click a button], etc. I can use the "appAPI.browserAction.setPopup()" method to create a popup or use the "sidebar" plugin to display the opened browser tabs/windows.

**Q-1.**  What are the advantages/disadvantages of using one over the other?
**Q-2.**  Is there any other method to do this?
**Q-3.**  How to monitor and display the opened browser tabs/windows?

Also, I want to use remote server [my website's server] to host the "Images, JavaScript and CSS" files so that the extension's "look and feel" and "functionality" can be continuously updated without the user keep re-installing the extension and without increasing the size of the extension. I know that I can use the "Resources" folder for the "Images, JavaScript and CSS", but I prefer the above method for the development.

**Q-4.**  What's the best way to use the remotely hosted files in the extension?

Answer (score 3):

**A-1.** In general, the content of a button's [popup](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction-method-setPopup) is created afresh each time you click the extension button whereas the sidebar's content persists. Hence, in this instance where I presume you will want this information to be readily accessible, it makes sense to use the [sidebar plugin](http://crossrider.com/developer/plugins).

**A-2.** These methods encapsulate the core concepts of the two general methods for this kind of content, i.e. embed in a button popup or within the HTML page (i.e. the sidebar). Of course, there are all sorts of solutions available for how to display the content within the page ;-)

**A-3.** You can monitor tabs being created using [appAPI.tabs.onTabCreated](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.tabs-method-onTabCreated) and use the callback function to perform any tasks you require. However, bear in mind that due to browser limitations, the method only detects new tabs created in the current browser instance.

**A-4.** This question is a bit tricky to answer without knowing more about the anatomy of your extension. I am assuming you want to inject this content into pages or use JS in your extension. Therefore, remote files can be included depending on the scope using [appAPI.resources](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.resources), [appAPI.dom](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.dom), or jQuery, as follows:

In the *extension.js* file:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // Includes remote JS file into extension.js scope
  appAPI.resources.includeRemoteJS('http://example.com/file.js');

  // Injects remote JS file into HTML page
  appAPI.dom.addRemoteJS('http://example.com/file.js');

  // Injects remote CSS file into HTML page
  appAPI.dom.addRemoteCSS('http://example.com/file.css');

  // Injects remote image file into HTML page
  $('<img src="http://example.com/file.png">').appendTo('body');
});
```

In the *background.js* file:

```
appAPI.ready(function() {
  var remoteJS = appAPI.resources.get('http://example.com/file.js');
  eval(remoteJS);
});
```

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee